# Adding custom tabs in administrator interface

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm pretty new to Wordpress theming, and I was wondering how to create custom tabs in the admin interface.

Once in a while when you install a new theme, a bunch of custom tabs emerge to the left, like these:
[image]

How do i make custom tabs? What are they called; "Custom tabs" or?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is called Administration_Menus, refer codex here http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Comment: Please write an answer, and I will approve it as the correct one.. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code from wordpress codex

1 . Create a function that contains the menu-building code
2 . Register the above function using the admin_menu action hook. (If you are adding an admin menu for the Network, use network_admin_menu instead).
3 .Create the HTML output for the page (screen) displayed when the menu item is clicked

```
<?php
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}

/** Step 3. */
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

refer wordpress codex for more details [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus)